# Setting a minimum overlapping area using overlay_intersect in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, intersect

I want to use the `overlay_intersects` function to obtain a new column on a grid layer with 0,1 values.

The binary results should come from the eventual overlap between my grid and the Shapefile of a country. Basically, if the grid cell overlap land should be 1, and if not (so, overlap the sea) should be 0. This works all good.

My problem is that I would like to set the percentage of the grid that overlaps the land to be true or not. For example, it should result 1 if at least 51% of the cell overlaps land.

In [QGIS list of functions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-geometrygroup-overlay-intersects) I found that there is another optional argument, "min_overlap", that should make the task. Unfortunately, I tried to use it, but seems it's not an appropriate argument within QGIS, and If I find to correct the expression it just returns null values. If I omit the argument, the function works good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the *min_overlap* argument is that per the documentation (my bold):

> for polygons, a minimum area in **current feature squared units** for the
> intersection

So you're comparing to 0.51 square units, not 51%.

Also, if you're getting an invalid error with *min_overlap*, you may not be using a recent enough version of QGIS.

Something like the following is probably close to the minimum expression:

```
area(
    intersection($geometry, 
        aggregate( 
            layer:='Country', 
            aggregate:='collect', 
            expression:=$geometry)
        )
    ) >= 0.51 * area($geometry)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input! Unfortunately, your expression returns me only NULL values. I don't understand the reason

Comment: Some things you can try: 1. Post a sample of your data - given it's working on my sample data, it's going to be hard to debug without your data. 2. Break down the expression above and find out which part of the expression is returning NULL

Comment: Also check that you're running the most recent version of QGIS (or the long term release version)

Comment: Hi! Probably the error was some unknown bug that solved itself. Basically, when I created a brand-new grid (with same specs), it worked out. 
I was already using the latest version of QGIS and the code works now, so I cannot explain. 
Thank you for your help, really precious!